# Why won't zgrep show the actual matches?

Tags: shell, zgrep

#### Context

Let's say I have two files `a.txt` and `b.txt` with some content...

```sh
$ tail *.txt
==> a.txt <==
ABC
CDE
123
C

==> b.txt <==
C
321
EDC
CBA
```

Let's also imagine that the files have now been put in a gzipped tarball...

```sh
$ tar -czf tarball.tgz *.txt
$ tar -tf tarball.tgz
a.txt
b.txt
```

#### Goal

Now, I want to grep through the files in the tarball. Seeing the original file-name and line-number before the match would be nice, but I most importantly want to see the matched lines.

#### What did I try?

First, I expected that `zgrep 'pattern' tarball.tgz` would simply work. It does tell me whether there is a match, it can even count them, but I can't find a way to have the matches printed...

```sh
$ zgrep 'AB' tarball.tgz
Binary file (standard input) matches
$ zgrep 'C' tarball.tgz
Binary file (standard input) matches
$ zgrep -c 'AB' tarball.tgz
1
$ zgrep -c 'C' tarball.tgz
6
```

Second, I thought to `zcat` the tarball and use a regular grep on that. But still, I get this exact same *"Binary file (standard input) matches"* message...

```sh
$ zcat tarball.tgz | grep 'C'
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

I guess `zcat` (and `zgrep`) do a `gunzip` but no `tar -xf`? If I look at `zcat` I can see the same output as if I had just done `tar -c`...

```sh
$ zcat tarball.tgz
a.txt0000664�3���3���0000000001613554050266013370 0ustar  useruserABC
CDE
123
C
b.txt0000664�3���3���0000000001613554050301013357 0ustar  useruserC
321
EDC
CBA

$ tar -c *.txt
a.txt0000664�3���3���0000000001613554050266013370 0ustar  useruserABC
CDE
123
C
b.txt0000664�3���3���0000000001613554050301013357 0ustar  useruserC
321
EDC
CBA
```

So finally, I got to this solution which works OK:

```sh
$ tar -xOzf tarball.tgz | grep 'C'
ABC
CDE
C
C
EDC
CBA
```

Of course, if I now ask for filenames and line-numbers, I don't get anything useful...

```sh
$ tar -xOzf tarball.tgz | grep -Hn 'C'
(standard input):1:ABC
(standard input):2:CDE
(standard input):4:C
(standard input):5:C
(standard input):7:EDC
(standard input):8:CBA
```

The only way I can think of, to get the results I want, would involve a bit more scripting to extract the tarball and run `grep` in a loop...

---

Is there a nice (easy and concise) way to do this?

Comment: grep doesn't understand the tar format; it's not going to magically tell you which individual file in the archive matches, no. Extracting files and grepping them is a good approach.

Comment: Oooh! [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528501/367593) on the Unix stackexchange might be very helpful.

Comment: Indeed @Shawn that answer has everything I needed: add `-a` for a quick and dirty approach, or use this `--to-command` option for the best possible output!

Do you want to post an answer? I will summarise in my own answer, otherwise.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions about *writing code*. Questions about the behavior of command-line UNIX tools when those tools are not "unique to software development" are a better fit for [unix.se]. There's a reason Shawn linked you to a question sited there, rather than on SO.

Comment: @Charles Duffy That sounds fair. I must admit I'm typically confused about which questions fit on which of the StackExchanges! Shall we close this question as inapropriate, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tar -czf` does two things:

- packages all files (which happen to be text only in my example) into a tar file (which is binary);
- gzips that tar file into a gzipped tar file.

As I was suspecting, `zgrep` or `zcat` will only do a `gunzip`, and be left with a tar file which is still binary. That explains all the output I was getting.

#### Easy solution

The easiest way around that is to add an option to `zgrep`:

```
   -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
```

That will work almost as good as `tar -xOzf tarball.tgz | grep -Hn 'C'`, where we don't get the individual filenames, and the line-numbers are over the whole tar output. We also get some noise, namely the `tar` format:

```sh
$ zgrep -Hna 'C' tarball.tgz
tarball.tgz:1:a.txt0000664�3���3���0000000001613554050266013370 0ustar  jlehuenjlehuenABC
tarball.tgz:2:CDE
tarball.tgz:4:C
tarball.tgz:5:b.txt0000664�3���3���0000000001613554050301013357 0ustar  jlehuenjlehuenC
tarball.tgz:7:EDC
tarball.tgz:8:CBA
```

That is easy enough to remember, and works quite well for e.g. grepping logs where the first line of the files is rarely the interesting matches.

#### Best output

Now, @Shawn pointed me to [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528501/367593) on the Unix StackExchange. From that, I could come up to my favorite option:

```sh
$ tar -xf tarball.tgz --to-command='grep -Hn --label="$TAR_ARCHIVE/$TAR_FILENAME" C || true'
tarball.tgz/a.txt:1:ABC
tarball.tgz/a.txt:2:CDE
tarball.tgz/a.txt:4:C
tarball.tgz/b.txt:1:C
tarball.tgz/b.txt:3:EDC
tarball.tgz/b.txt:4:CBA
```

I'll probably create myself some function for this, because it's not fun to type. The output is exactly what I wanted, though! :)